# how to show all users that are not starting with letter "t" in kali linux

Tags: command-line, kali-linux

I want to ask about kali linux,
please,
how to show all users that are not starting with letter "t" in kali linux?

I tried grep and cat but it shows all the users, I want just the ones not starting with "t"

Comment: Why do you think this is a Kali Linux specific question? What have you researched or tried on your own?

Comment: removed the debian tag and used kali-linux, though it's questionable *either* tag should be used – but debian is clearly the wrong tag, since this is kali, not normal debian.

Comment: Check the `passwd` file, use `grep` and `cut`.

Comment: Cut is for those who don't know how to use awk.  :-P

Comment: @user10489 and grepping `/etc/passwd` is for those who don’t know how to use `getent` :-P

Comment: I tried grep and cat but it shows all the users, I want just the ones not starting with "t"

Comment: I don't see how to filter with getent, it just picks exact entries.  I suppose getent makes a good poor man's finger though. :) And if you can't do it with grep, you aren't paying attention to what grep does.

Comment: Mouhcine ELFADILI, _how did you_ try `grep` and `cat`? Please [edit] your question to show what you tried so we can help you learn what was wrong

Comment: @user10489 my point isn’t about `grep`, it’s about `/etc/passwd`, which isn’t necessarily the source of truth for user accounts.

Comment: How is this a request for learning materials?

Comment: @MouhcineELFADILI You should [edit] your question and copy&paste the code you tried and show the input, actual and expected output. Then we can help you to fix the errors in your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -v ^t /etc/passwd
```

Or, to get fancier:

```
awk -F: '!/^t/ { print $1,$5}' /etc/passwd
```